# Green's and Stoke's theorem area calculation disambiguation

Tags: calculus, integration, differential-geometry, definite-integrals, vector-analysis

In 2D one may use Green's theorem to calculate the area of a closed curve quite easily.

Assume the curve is parametrized by:

$r(t)=\langle x(t),y(t)\rangle$

$a \leq t \leq b.$

Then we get:

$dx=x'(t)dt$; $dy=y'(t)dt.$

And finally through a clever application of Green's theorem:

$$A = \frac{1}{2}\int^b_a \big(-y(t)x'(t)+x(t)y'(t)\big)dt$$

Does this mean that Stoke's theorem can be used to calculate the "minimal" area described by a curve in 3D?

If yes how, if not why not?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2469226/how-to-find-the-area-enclosed-between-two-curves-in-3-dimensions you might find the comments section of this interesting

Comment: Let's say you have a simple closed curve $\gamma$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, there are many surfaces $\Omega$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ having $\gamma$ as boundary. The area $A = \frac12 \int_\Omega dS$ is different for different $\Omega$. However, up to a sign, the area weighted normal vector $\vec{A} = \frac12 \int_\Omega \hat{n}dS$ is the same. It can be expressed as a line integral over $\gamma$. (i.e. $\vec{A} = \frac12 \int_\gamma \vec{r} \times d\vec{r}$ ).The magnitude of $\vec{A}$ is an lower bound of area. ( i.e. $|\vec{A}| \le A$ ). In fact, if $\gamma$ is planar, we have $|\vec{A}| = A$.

Comment: Hmm. last line should be "if $\gamma$ is planar, we have $|\vec{A}|$ equals to minimum area of those $\Omega$ having $\gamma$ as boundary.